# Unable to export SVG graph using http://d3export.housegordon.org/

Tags: apache, perl

I am trying to export an SVG graph as an attachment to download. I am using http://d3export.housegordon.org/ to achieve the same. The perl file returns a status message of 200OK. Neither the apache log nor the perl log is showing any errors. Also, I am able to print the output SVG string of the perl file in my console which I assume is indicative of the request to perl file being successful. However, instead of getting an SVG attachment file to download as response, an extra tab gets opened displaying an APACHE ERROR which reads..."**Not Found
The requested URL /[object XMLDocument] was not found on this server.**". I have made a few modifications in my perl script wrt the perl script provided on the link mentioned above. My modified perl script is as below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser/;
use autodie qw(:all);
use File::Temp qw/tempfile/;
use File::Slurp qw/read_file write_file/;

$CGI::POST_MAX = 1024 * 5000;

my $output_format = param("output_format")
or die "Missing 'output_format' parameter";
die "Invalid output_format value"
unless $output_format eq "svg" ||
    $output_format eq "pdf" ||
    $output_format eq "png";

my $data = param("data")
or die "Missing 'data' parameter";
die "Invalid data value"
unless $data =~ /^[\x20-\x7E\t\n\r ]+$/;

my $timestamp = time;
my $random = int(rand(99999));
my $dnldfile = "/dnld/d3Momentum" . $timestamp . "_" . $random . ".svg";
my $filename = "/var/www/html/Project/Project_frontend/public".$dnldfile;
my $q = CGI->new;

if ($output_format eq "svg") {
print $q->header(-type=>"image/svg+xml", -attachment=>$filename,);
print $data;

exit(0);
}
elsif ($output_format eq "pdf" || $output_format eq "png") {
my (undef, $input_file) = tempfile("d3export.svg.XXXXXXX", OPEN=>0, TMPDIR=>1, UNLINK=>1);
my (undef, $output_file) = tempfile("d3export.out.XXXXXXX", OPEN=>0, TMPDIR=>1, UNLINK=>1);
write_file( $input_file, $data );

my $zoom = ($output_format eq "png")?10:1;

system("rsvg-convert -o '$output_file' -z '$zoom' -f '$output_format' '$input_file'");

my $pdf_data = read_file( $output_file, {binmode=>':raw'});

my $mime_type = ($output_format eq "pdf")?"application/x-pdf":"image/png";
print header(-type=>$mime_type,
         -attachment=>"d3js_export_demo.$output_format");
print $pdf_data;

exit(0);
}
```

Request Parameters being passed are..
'ouput_format' : 'svg'; 
'data' : (Entire SVG Element parsed using XMLSerializer.serializeToString() as mentioned on http://d3export.housegordon.org/).

Below is my Virtual Host Configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project-v4.co
    ServerAlias project-v4.co
    Alias /awstatsclasses "/usr/share/awstats/lib/"
      Alias /awstats-icon "/usr/share/awstats/icon/"
      Alias /awstatscss "/usr/share/doc/awstats/examples/css"
      ScriptAlias /awstats/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Project-v4/Project-v4_frontend/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "production"
    <Directory /var/www/html/Project-v4/Project-v4_frontend/public>
            DirectoryIndex index.html
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    AddHandler cgi-script .bin
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/html/Project-v4/Project-v4_frontend/public/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/var/www/html/Project-v4/Project-v4_frontend/public/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    #ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/live-error.log
    ErrorLog /var/www/live-error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

#<Location /perl/>
    #        SetHandler perl-script
     #       PerlHandler ModPerl::PerlRun
      #      Options ExecCGI
    #</Location>
```

Below is the Ajax Call to the perl script.

```
 var oData = {"output_format" : "svg", "data" : svg_xml};

  $.ajax({
        url: '/cgi-bin/d3export.pl',
        method: "POST",
        data:  oData,
        success: function(oResult) {
          console.log(oResult);
          window.open(oResult);
        }
      })
```

The Perl script is located in the cgi-bin directory, which is located in the public folder of my Project (Project-v4_frontend/public/cgi-bin/d3export.pl). I am using the MEAN stack for my project.

Any help to resolve the apache NOT FOUND error would be appreciated sincerely.

Thank You.

Comment: Why do you add svg, d3.js and javascript tag? This looks like a apache/perl issue. Also you do not specify your webserver setup, and how the perl script is called.

Comment: Added VirtualHost Config File and Ajax call to the Perl script.